# variation of objects falling with different properties

Tags: javascript, object

I'm a beginner to programming, and i'm creating a simple 2 player game where players move left and right on the bottom of the screen and collect falling objects - objects which will have different properties i.e. speed up players/slow them down.

I've created one object to fall but not sure how to go about creating multiple objects to fall.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
///// this is the food.js for falling food //////

var Food = function(type){


  var position = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  var foodElement = null;

  // this will run at every frame
  this.render = function(gravity){
    console.log(position.x, position.y);
    position.y += gravity;
    foodElement.style.top = position.y + "px";
  }

  // This will only run once
  function init(){
    foodElement = document.createElement("div");
    foodElement.classList.add("food");
    foodElement.classList.add(type);

    position.x = parseInt(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
    foodElement.style.top = position.y + "px";
    foodElement.style.left = position.x + "px";

    var gameBoard = document.getElementById("gameboard");
    gameBoard.appendChild(foodElement);
  }

  init();

}

function (createFood) {

}
```

Comment: You need to create instances of *Food* with `new Food(...)`. Each instance can then behave independently. I much prefer function declarations to expressions, but to each their own.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to create the new Food in the engine.